# Anndroid App + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

Estoy realizando una app para **Android** que haga un login a un server en **MySQL**, este debe de pasar antes por un archivo php donde se conecte al server y recoja el usuario y contraseña de quien se vaya a logear.
Realicé el archivo php que se conecta con el server (voy por pasos que soy nuevo en esto) hasta aquí bien, el navegador me devuelve que el server está conectado.

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "abc123.", "clients");
if($conn->connect_errno>0){
die('Imposible conectar['.$conn->connect_errno.']');
}else{
echo 'Conectado';
} 
?>
```

En la app de Android le añadí el archivo php de conectado o no conectado, pero, cuando inicio la app en el móvil físico me salta al catch de la clase httpHandler, supongo que no es capaz de leer el php.
**MainActivity**:

```
public class WindowPrincipalLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView status;
private String txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.windowgraphic_pl);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    httpHandler han = new httpHandler();
    txt = han.post("http://localhost/prueba/conn.php");
    status.setText(txt);
```

Clase a la que llamo desde la Main que ejecuta el hilo:

```
public class httpHandler {

public String post(String posturl){
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(posturl);
        HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
        String text = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
        return text;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Fallo en la conexión al servidor"+e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Para esto, la mejor opción es usar `Volley` de Android, y emitir respuestas en formato JSON desde el servidor. [Aquí tienes más detalles](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) (mira el ejemplo de Java, no el de Kotlin).

Comment: Que tal pedro, seria necesario si también agregar el log que te envio de error, Asegurate de saber si estas pidiendo los permisos de internet en tu aplicación, otra para conectarte al al host de tu pc, debes ingresar con `10.0.2.2` si mal no recuerdo

Comment: Vale he realizado el proyecto como me dijisteis con Volley y poniéndole la url http://10.0.2.2/prueba/conn.php @Miguel Osorio parece que quiere ir, le añadí más tiempo de carga a 30 segundos pero es como si no encontrase el php que tengo en local.

Comment: Nada fue fallo mio tenia que poner la ip que tiene mi pc asignada. Gracias pos vuestras ayudas